# How can I make my Tumblr blog hide the source?

Tags: tumblr

On my Tumblr blog, I want to make it look nice but I don't like it when the source and tags are shown. How do I hide these?

Comment: you can't hide HTML if that's what you're asking. the browser needs to have the source otherwise it won't render.

Answer (score 2):

Hiding the source on your Tumblr theme means that users will not know where the content came from and you will be accountable for not showing attribution. Nevertheless, you need to change settings within your Tumblr theme via [Customize preferences](http://www.tumblr.com/customize).

For tags you need to remove `{block:HasTags} {/block:HasTags}`

Answer (score 1):

To hide the source and via when reflagging content just simply look for `{block:ContentSource}{/block:ContentSource}` and replace it with this code:

```
{block:ContentSource}<!-- {SourceURL}{block:SourceLogo}<img src="{BlackLogoURL}"
width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />{/block:SourceLogo}{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo} -->{block:NoSourceLogo}{/block:NoSourceLogo}{/block:ContentSource}{block:ReblogParent}{/block:ReblogParent}
```

And there you have it.